# Why can't I update my Lambda LayerVersion using SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

When I use sam deploy to update a layer or even just re-run the SAM template I run into problems. Even if I haven't changed the actual layer, because of how SAM packages the layers CF thinks things are getting updated. That aside the error I see in the CF events looks like this:

[image]

I set the RetentionPolicy of the layer to Retain but that doesn't seem to have the desired effect. Is there anything I can do other than delete downstream resources, or create a new stack with new names and switch all the downstream resources over to the new layers?

**Update**

Here's a sample from my SAM template. Is there something I should change?

```
    Resources:
      LoggingLayer:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
        Properties:
          LayerName: !Ref LoggingLayerName
          Description: Hyphensolutions Logging Layer
          ContentUri: logging/
          LicenseInfo: 'MIT'
          RetentionPolicy: Retain
        Metadata:
          BuildMethod: nodejs12.x
```

Comment: Do you use the layer outside your CFN stack?

Comment: Yes. As one of the errors implies there is a different stack that references the layer. I get that. What concerns me is that CF claims it has to create a new physical resource even if I haven't made changes to the layer. I'm assuming this is because I do a clean build and generate new packages with different names from the previous deployment. Seems strange that CF needs to re-create the layer. I can just delete the stacks that reference the layer but it seems to me like that wouldn't be neccessary.

Comment: Did you change your `LoggingLayerName`? If layer name changes, the resource has to be re-created.

Comment: Nope. Didn't change the LoggingLayerName but that would make sense if I had.

Comment: Do you have a minimal example and command sequences to reproduce your issue? And moving the conversation to https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues is also a good idea.